# If $t>w$, how much greater is the sum of $s$ and $t$ than the sum of $s$ and $w$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $t>w$, how much greater is the sum of $s$ and $t$ than the sum of $s$ and $w$?

(A)  $s-t$

(B)  $2s-w$

(C)  $t-w$

(D)  $t+w$

(E)  $2s-t-w$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine, knowing $\;t>w$,

$$\large\underbrace{\;\;s + t\;\;}_{\large\text{sum of s and t}}  {\bf{-}} \underbrace{\;\;(s + w)\;\;}_{\large\text{sum of s and w}}$$

*using Zev's reminder that*:
 $a - (b+c) = a - b - c\tag{*}$

Here, we want to determine, knowing that $t>w$, the following value, which you need only simplify: $$s+t - (s+w)\; = \;s + t - s - w\tag{*}$$

Comment: Therefore after adding you get $t-w$ as the answer.

Comment: Very good! Yes indeed. In problems like this, it's good to get in the practice of carefully *translating* the words into a mathematical problem that you can solve. Now, that wasn't too bad, was it?

Comment: nope straightforward and simple!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** "How much greater is $x$ than $y$?" means "Find the value of $x-y$."

Also, keep in mind that that $a-(b+c)=a-b-c$.

Comment: I am sorry I am kind of lost there. :(

Comment: The sum of $s$ and $t$ is $s+t$. The sum of $s$ and $w$ is $s+w$. You want to find the value of
$$(s+t)-(s+w).$$